# Fetching and organizing data and rendering the response

Tags: reactjs

total noob looking for some help with react and handling data from a response.

When data is structured like this I have no problem - I can render it just fine.

```json
[{
    "id":"90",
    "symbol":"BTC",
    "name":"Bitcoin",
    "nameid":"bitcoin",
    "rank":1,
    "price_usd":"42674.97",
    "percent_change_24h":"-3.66",
    "percent_change_1h":"0.71",
    "percent_change_7d":"-10.16",
    "market_cap_usd":"803057883424.85",
    "volume24":"36258318378.29",
    "volume24_native":"849639.08",
    "csupply":"18818009.00",
    "price_btc":"1.00",
    "tsupply":"18818009",
    "msupply":"21000000"
}]
```

like such

```
this.state = {
      coins: [] ... 

<h1 key={coins.id}> {coins.name} {coins.price_usd} </h1>
```

However when it's an array of lists like this I have a problem.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "bitcoin",
      "rank": "1",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "supply": "17193925.0000000000000000",
      "maxSupply": "21000000.0000000000000000",
      "marketCapUsd": "119150835874.4699281625807300",
      "volumeUsd24Hr": "2927959461.1750323310959460",
      "priceUsd": "6929.8217756835584756",
      "changePercent24Hr": "-0.8101417214350335",
      "vwap24Hr": "7175.0663247679233209"
    },

    {
      "id": "bibox-token",
      "rank": "100",
      "symbol": "BIX",
      "name": "Bibox Token",
      "supply": "102339166.0000000000000000",
      "maxSupply": null,
      "marketCapUsd": "72116102.5394724649666992",
      "volumeUsd24Hr": "45084130.4166935808283857",
      "priceUsd": "0.7046774500729512",
      "changePercent24Hr": "-3.0331628584946192",
      "vwap24Hr": "0.7207903092174193"
    }
  ],
}
```

when I see anything that is prefixed with `"data:[{...` I stumble I think it has todo with `coins: []`, do I set the state with `data.coins`?.

I was raised to think there are no dumb questions... however I really feel like I'm overlooking something simple and my brain hurts.

Comment: use `.map()` if ur data is an array of objects

Comment: You need an array state, then you can access the object like  ```<h1 key={coins[index].id}> {coins[index].name} {coins[index].price_usd} </h1>```

Comment: can you add more clarification like the error message you receive, more code that tells us what you are actually doing.

Comment: What is `data.coins`? Can you not save the `data` array into state to be rendered as an array, it appears to have the same general object shape? Your question/issue is unclear. Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and more details about what isn't working and what, if any, debugging you've done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting response like **data: [{id:1,...}, {id:2,...}]**
You need set your response to your state like **this.setState({ coins: response.data })**

Here an example

```
const response = {
    data: [
    {
      id: "bitcoin",
      rank: "1",
      symbol: "BTC",
      name: "Bitcoin",
      supply: "17193925.0000000000000000",
      maxSupply: "21000000.0000000000000000",
      marketCapUsd: "119150835874.4699281625807300",
      volumeUsd24Hr: "2927959461.1750323310959460",
      priceUsd: "6929.8217756835584756",
      changePercent24Hr: "-0.8101417214350335",
      vwap24Hr: "7175.0663247679233209"
    },

    {
      id: "bibox-token",
      rank: "100",
      symbol: "BIX",
      name: "Bibox Token",
      supply: "102339166.0000000000000000",
      maxSupply: null,
      marketCapUsd: "72116102.5394724649666992",
      volumeUsd24Hr: "45084130.4166935808283857",
      priceUsd: "0.7046774500729512",
      changePercent24Hr: "-3.0331628584946192",
      vwap24Hr: "0.7207903092174193"
    }
  ]
};

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      coins: []
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({ coins: response.data });
}
```

You can access data by *this.state.coins[0].name* or map()